# Why does $\mathrm{d}\phi' = \mathrm{d}\phi$ in the derivation of Lorentz transformation of Solid angles?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, visible-light

Let $O$ and $O'$ be two inertial frames where $O'$ moves with velocity $v$ relative to $O$ along the $+x$ direction. A light beam of intersection angle $\theta$ with the $x$ axis in frame $O$ has a different intersection angle $\theta'$ with the $x'$ axis in the frame $O'$. The transformation rule reads
$$ \cos\theta' = \frac{\cos\theta - \beta}{1-\beta\cos\theta},\quad \text{where} \quad \beta = \frac{v}{c}. $$
(For derivations, see [Relativistic beaming/ Aberration effect derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/493619/relativistic-beaming-aberration-effect-derivation?rq=1), for example, which is a simple application of the Lorentz transformation.)

Now if we have a collection of light beams that radiate from $\mathbf{r}=\boldsymbol{0}$ to a solid angle $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ in the frame $O$, we know that these light beams radiate to a different solid angle $\mathrm{d}\Omega'$ in the frame $O'$ (because $\cos\theta$ changes to $\cos\theta'$).

We may find $\mathrm{d}\Omega'$ in terms of $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ as follows (for simplicity we assume that $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ lies at $\phi = 0$, i.e. the light beams are roughly near the $xz$ plane):
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}\Omega' &= \mathrm{d}\cos\theta' \mathrm{d}\phi' = \frac{\mathrm{d} \cos\theta'}{d \cos\theta}\frac{\mathrm{d}\phi'}{\mathrm{d}\phi}\, \mathrm{d}\cos\theta \,\mathrm{d}\phi \\
&= \frac{1-\beta^2}{(1-\beta\cos\theta)^2}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi'}{\mathrm{d}\phi} \cdot \mathrm{d}\Omega \\
&= \frac{1-\beta^2}{(1-\beta\cos\theta)^2} \mathrm{d}\Omega.
\end{align*}$$
(See, for example, [page 47 of this pdf](https://apatruno.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/lecture41.pdf), [page 28 of this pdf](http://background.uchicago.edu/%7Ewhu/Courses/Ast305_10/ast305_06.pdf), or [page 13 or this pdf](https://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/%7Ealgera/pages/RP1718/Lecture6.pdf), which all arrive at exactly the same expression except for the different signs before $\beta\cos\theta$ in the denominator caused by a different choice of the moving direction of $O'$ relative to $O$.)

The above derivation looks all good except for the last step where we assumed that $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi'}{\mathrm{d}\phi} = 1$. Some authors argued that ${\mathrm{d}\phi'} ={\mathrm{d}\phi}$ because the line segment of $\mathrm{d}{\phi}$ is perpendicular to $x$, the direction of moving, thus invariant under Lorentz transformations.

However, this statement doesn't sound quite right to me. What is invariant under the Lorentz transformations should be $\mathrm{d}p_y$ and $\mathrm{d}p_z$, i.e. the $y$ and $z$ components of the momenta of the light beams. But $\mathrm{d}\phi$, defined by (remember that we have assumed $\phi \rightarrow 0$)
$$ \mathrm{d}\phi = \frac{\mathrm{d}p_y}{p_x}, $$
does change under Lorentz transformation as
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\phi'}{\mathrm{d}\phi} = \frac{p_x}{p_x'} \neq 1, $$
which invalidates the above derivation.

The final expression of $\mathrm{d}\Omega'$ appears in much literature and must be correct. Therefore, I must have missed some points in the proof. Could someone explain why ${\mathrm{d}\phi'} ={\mathrm{d}\phi}$?

Comment: I don't get why you think $\text{d}\phi =\frac{\text{d} p_y}{p_x}$. Where does this come from? Also, what about the argument of $\text{d}\phi$ being perpendicular to $x$ don't you like?

Comment: To clarify: In problems with such "beams", I seem to remember that the coordinate system used is usually with what would "conventionally" be called the $z-$axis pointing along the beam's direction of motion. In this sense the "azimuthal" angle $\phi$ is the angle around the beam axis and therefore always perpendicular to it. (I may be mis-remembering, but perhaps you can include this in your answer?)